# Search by thread rather than email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, search

Gmail seems to have a flaw insofar as it acts as though tags apply only to the first email in a thread rather than to the whole thread (or to all emails in a thread).

This means that if I *send* an email, tag the thread "to-do" and then get a reply in the same thread, searching for `in:inbox label:to-do` won't show the thread in the results, despite the fact that the thread is in my inbox and is tagged "to-do".

*Searching for `in:sent label:to-do` will show the thread, but if I'm only interested in finding threads that are in my inbox (rather than archived threads, or messages that I've sent but which haven't yet received replies), then this is no help.*

So, is it possible to search by thread rather than by email in Gmail?

Comment: are you sure it is in your inbox? I have not been able to recreate the issue. Many people forget that inbox is just a label.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Yes, I'm sure. And yes, the same result occurs with `label:inbox ...` as with `in:inbox ...`

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I now think there may be something subtler going on: http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/gmail/ip2APz_Kwlw/discussion

Answer (score 2):

Tags are meant for individual messages not threads. The reply will not have the label on it because you have not labelled the message as such. You will want to apply a filter to grab any new messages.

Turn off conservation view and you will be able to search by individual message.

[image: Conversation View in settings]

Example filters that could work for your thread

> Matches: from:(sender@gmail.com) to:(phwd@gmail.com) subject:(Blank
>   Test) Do this: Apply label "To-Do"
>
> Matches: from:(phwd@gmail.com) to:(sender@gmail.com) subject:(Blank
>   Test) Do this: Apply label "To-Do"

With conversation view off, you should see both the sent message and received message using `label:to-do` and only the received items with `label:to-do in:inbox`

Comment: Thank you. This is somewhat helpful, but does not provide a solution to the [more specific question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28836/6757) *How do I find every thread in a Gmail account matching both of the following conditions: (1) The thread is among the threads displayed in the "inbox" view. (2) The thread is labeled (or contains a message that is labeled) "To-do".*

Comment: The solution may - if what you say about tags is correct - require invoking a mechanism to discover each of the other emails in a thread given one of the emails in the thread, and then checking each of those emails to see if any of them is in the inbox, and if so, adding that thread to the search results. So, does such a mechanism exist, or alternatively can one be created using some kind of API/plugin mechanism? If so, what/how? Thanks again.

Comment: @sampablokuper threads cannot be labelled. only messages. With conversation view on, what you are seeing in the search results are threads with message tagged. There is no mechanism you seek other than adding a filter with the subject and to field and the label so the incoming message gets added to the label.

Comment: I'm puzzled. You say, "There is no mechanism you seek other than adding a filter with the **subject** and **to field** and the label so the incoming message gets added to the label," but neither the **subject field** nor the **to field** are relevant to my questions.

Comment: @sampablokuper Filters are able to "tag" threads (or more so they are able to tag messages within a tag). In order to define what messages are in a tag you will need to assign parameters to your filter. If you have a subject field that helps, you are sending the message "to" someone so that helps as well. So they are relevant. See example above.

Comment: phwd, thanks, but I still don't see how either the subject field or the to field is relevant. I'm interested in finding *all* threads showing in the inbox and which have (one or more emails tagged with) a particular tag. I have no other information whatsoever about those threads: i.e. it doesn't matter to me who started the thread, who received emails in the thread, nor what the subject was. Does this help you see why I think neither the **subject field** nor the **to field** are relevant to my questions?

Comment: @sampablokuper This is leading in a circle. "So, is it possible to search by thread rather than by email in Gmail?" `No` "How to find every thread that is both listed in inbox and is also tagged with a particular tag?" `No impossible, see former question` You cannot have threads labelled. If you are in a thread (whether you started it or not) and you label the message you are currently composing, you are labelling your message not the thread. If you need to label incoming messages then you need a filter. Using the subject field and to field is one way to do this whether you use it is up to you

Comment: How, then, can I get conjunction of the set of threads I get when I search for "labels:To-do" and the set of threads I get when I search for "in:inbox"?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to set up a filter to label all incoming messages of possible interest, since they are already labelled: i.e. they are labelled "inbox".

Comment: @sampablokuper This is still going in a circle: `How, then, can I get conjunction of the set of threads I get when I search for "labels:To-do" and the set of threads I get when I search for "in:inbox"?` => **Threads cannot be labelled only the messages within, you cannot search by thread, conversation view is a design not a search feature** `It doesn't make sense to me to set up a filter to label all incoming messages of possible interest, since they are already labelled: i.e. they are labelled "inbox"` => `You wanted to label messages with To-Do :S`

Comment: I don't want to *automatically* label anything "To-do", except, perhaps, all other messages in a thread in which one message is already marked "To-do" - which would then let me search as though the label "To-do" applied to the thread rather than to the message. If there's a way to do this, please tell me; but I don't think filters are up to the task. I'm looking through the API docs now; is there, for instance, some way to find [thread IDs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_thread_id_x-gm-thrid) through the Gmail web interface?

Comment: PS. If it seems like I'm having trouble accepting this as a hard limitation of Gmail then it's because it seems to me like such obviously useful functionality that I find it difficult to believe Gmail's developers failed to provide it.

Comment: I've pinged the Gmail Community Manager across at Google+ hopefully they will chime in when get a chance, other than that there is not much more I can do in terms of an end user non-programming solution, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, phwd :) Although it would be ideal to get a solution that doesn't require programming, if you've got a solution that *does* require programming, I'd still be interested in it, so please do post a link to the relevant JSfiddle or PasteBin or what-have-you.